# Script for updating sequences with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 for a JEE Application (JSF, JPA, EclipseLink).

I restart my database weekly and doing that I need to update the sequence of all my tables like that:

```
UPDATE[dbo].[SEQUENCE] 
SET [SEQ_COUNT] = (SELECT MAX(IDAGENCE) 
                   FROM AGENCE) 
WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_AGENCE'
```

My question is: how do I trigger a script when I restart my database to update all my sequences?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but take a look at [this blog post](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/02/01/running-code-on-the-startup-of-sql-server/) - it was the first thing to show up when I Googled for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in stored procedure in SQL Server, `sp_procoption`, that lets you designate a stored procedure to run when the server restarts. You would use it like this:

```
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'MyProcedure', @OptionName = 'STARTUP', @OptionValue = 'ON'
```